# Trying to initialize keys from an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, hash

Searched for an answer but did not get far.  Here's what I'm doing: I have a Parser class that is returning an array of hashes.  I'm trying to import the data into another class and set the keys up as instance variables and then start doing some cool stuff.  I keep seeing "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)" when trying to establish the instance variables.  What am I missing?

```
class Parser
  attr_accessor :recipe_array
  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
    @zip_array = []
    run
  end

  def run
    replace_ingredient_commas
    make_recipe_array
    parse_for_zip
    make_hash
    get_args
  end

  def replace_ingredient_commas
    @recipe_array = File.read(@filename).gsub!((/,\ /),'. ')
  end

  def make_recipe_array
    @recipe_array = @recipe_array.split(",")
  end

  def parse_for_zip
    @recipe_headers = @recipe_array.shift(5)
    3.times do
      @zip_array.push(@recipe_array.shift(4))
    end
# unable to resolve disappearing id numbers with regexp or with the split.  Fixing it here.  Refact opp.
    counter = 1
    @zip_array.each do |recipe|
      recipe.unshift(counter)
      counter += 1
     end
  end

  def make_hash
    # @recipe_hash = Hash.new
    @args = @zip_array.map do |recipe|
      Hash[@recipe_headers.zip(recipe)]
    end
    p @args
  end

  def get_args
   @args
  end

end

class Bistro
  attr_reader :id, :name, :description, :ingredients, :directions
  def initialize(args ={})

    @id           = args[:id]
    @name         = args[:name]
    @description  = args[:description]
    @ingredients  = args[:ingredients]
    @directions   = args[:directions]

  end
end

# TESTS

parsed_info = Parser.new("recipes.csv")
bistro_test = Bistro.new(parsed_info.get_args)
```

Comment: `parsed_info.get_args` is an array, not hash. `Array#[]` only accepts integers, so `args[:id]` is an invalid call.

Comment: While including your full code is helpful, it's even more helpful to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when asking a question. As is, I can't reproduce your error because I don't have a `recipes.csv` file to run it with.